# Fatal error: Call to undefined function _setlocale() - phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When opening phpMyAdmin at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ address the following error message appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _setlocale() in
>   /var/www/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 488

Does anyone know what can it be?

I use Linux Mint with PHP Version 5.6.29

Comment: Unless you're a PHP hacker who's contributing to the PhpMyAdmin project this question is probably off-topic here. Does the software have a support forum?

Comment: Please check the permissions of folders and files of phpMyAdmin. The apache user/group should have extensive rights.

Comment: Permissions are for writing and reading in all phpmyadmin folders and files. What else can I check? Can this be related to the version of my php or lack of any library?